# Validate associated model in different way

Tags: validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I have different models which belong to a company model:

```
# badge_holder.rb
class BadgeHolder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, allow_destroy: false, reject_if: :all_blank
end

# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, allow_destroy: false, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

A company in context of a badge holder needs some more information (such as address data) as in context of an user.

To be sure that a company without context has all possibly needed attributes I would set the validators within the company model:

```
# company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   validates_presence_of :name, :address, :zip, :city
end
```

Using the badge holder and user form both with company as nested attributes in the form:

Is there a way to revoke the validator partially in context of the user form (address, zip, and city are optional)?

Comment: I'd look into Form Objects and add the validations to the forms not the models.  There is an old RailsCast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects which will give you some ideas.

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks for this hint.